# Single select tagfield issue with empty text

Tags: javascript, extjs, tagfield

I cannot use empty text with single select value. When I select the value it overlaps the empty text. And another is when a value is selected and I type something on tagfield and then erase it the selected value still appears but it does not give any value when I get it through getValue(). Is there any solution or workaround for it?
Here is the fiddle for single select tagfield.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ahl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id: 0` troubles the combobox. Probably it confuses it with an empty selection. Use only ids > 0 for your records.

Comment: The id is a number. I guess Ext does something like rec.get('valueField'). In that case 0 == false. Ext uses Ext.id to generate ids, this is always a string. So in case you store it as string, it will work as desired.